# Reason for question closure

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I want to know what is the exact reasoning (in detail) for the closure of [this question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/26088/30383). I also want to know what can be done (in regards to editing) to reopen the question.

Edit: This question was asked by another user, not me.

Comment: If you could include in your demands what's unclear about https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/26088/how-to-convince-my-parents-to-let-me-study-biotechnology-instead-of-mbbs#comment101747_26088, people may be actually inclined to help.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell that comment mention something that isn't clear about giving arguments being off the scope. I think I could find counterexamples in the site, and the help center doesn't mention this as offtopic unless I missed something. I think this is the main reason for closure and would benefit from e.g. a link to a relevant meta discussion. Some other part about abreviations got edited.

Comment: Would op not edit I might make a question about said topic

Comment: @Arthur the help center is very clear: "If you are having a dispute with your spouse or coworker, we are not going to settle the dispute for you *or give you points to argue*." (Emphasis mine because you missed it apparently). If there are counterexamples on the site they should be closed.

Answer (score 6):

Since I'm already at it in the comments, I left a comment that clearly states why I closed that question.

The OP of that question has provided no data of what arguments they tried to use to convince the parents and how they went about using those arguments. All we know is that OP told parents, but OP left out the most important *what they told* and *how they told*, like every other question on this site seems to do.

Without knowing the arguments OP has to convince their parents, we'd also be running into the limits as set out in our help/on-topic: we cannot give you points to argue and tell you what to say.

Without those details that only the asker can provide, we cannot help them improve their interpersonal skills. We'd only be throwing mud at a wall, hoping something would stick (like I'm doing here now because I have no clue what part of the original comment you didn't get). Just like demanding explanations on meta about old abandoned questions (there has been no activity from the OP there, making this just another hit and run question), throwing that mud is a waste of effort that doesn't improve site quality.

Comment: You asked the meaning of MBBS and NEET. I thought that the question was closed just because the author of the question didn't specify the meanings of those. I also suggested an edit and it was rejected. I added a lot about the context of the situation in the edit (https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/21434). Can you please look into the edit?

Comment: @technastic_tc The edit just adds more information about those acronyms; it doesn't address the main points that Tinkeringbell mentions here or in her comment.